# State-of-the-art results on molecular vibronic energy calculation

Tags: quantum-chemistry, energy, theoretical-chemistry

Could someone kindly point me to the latest records in scale, accuracy, or timescale for molecular vibronic energy calculation?

I tried to start with Google Scholar: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_ylo=2022&q=%22vibronic+energy%22&hl=en&as_sdt=0,21

From, that link I have found a few papers or work in progress, e.g.:

1. Mátyus, Edit, and Dávid Ferenc. "Vibronic mass computation for the $EF$-$GK$-$H\bar{H}$$^1\Sigma_\mathrm{g}^+$ manifold of molecular hydrogen." arXiv preprint arXiv:2201.13205 (2022).
2. Talbot, Justin J., et al. "Dynamic signatures of electronically nonadiabatic coupling in sodium hydride: a rigorous test for the symmetric quasi-classical model applied to realistic, ab initio electronic states in the adiabatic representation." Physical Chemistry Chemical Physics 24.8 (2022): 4820-4831.

I am wondering if there is a faster way to know the latest records.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139050/discussion-on-question-by-omar-shehab-state-of-the-art-results-on-molecular-vibr).